# Is a FilterController planned for sap.m.p13n.Popup

Tags: sapui5

I asked this already on the SAP community, but didn't get any response.

We wanted to move from the deprecated P13nDialog to the recommended P13nPopup. But we miss a controller for filtering. Is this planned? If yes, when will it be available?

If it is not planned, what is the recommended alternative for filtering sap.m.Table and sap.ui.table.Table?

Regards,

Heiko

Edit:
A code snippet is diffcult, because it would be too complex. But I hope I can clarify the subject a little bit more:

In our application we implemented a P13n solution for tables. With this, you can open a dialog where you have four panels to filter, group, sort and/or select columns.
This implementation is based on the P13n-Dialog (https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.P13nDialog). In this dialog you can add one of the following panels:
sap.m.P13nFilterPanel, sap.m.P13nGroupPanel, sap.m.P13nSortPanel and sap.m.P13nColumnsPanel.

Now all classes are marked deprecated except sap.m.P13nFilterPanel.
In the mentioned page, it is advised to move over to sap.m.p13n.Popup (https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.p13n.Popup).

As you can see on the API reference, for this new popup there are only Panels and Controllers for sorting, grouping and selection. But a panel and controller combination is missing for filtering. That means, that with the new popup there seems to be no possibility to filter. Also the control sample for the popup (https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.p13n.Popup/sample/sap.m.sample.p13n.Popup) does not have a panel for filtering.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with p13n modules. Could you enhance the question with the description and some code snippets how a "FilterController" was supported in `sap.m.P13nDialog`?

Comment: Thanks for the update. If you open https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/#/entity/sap.m.p13n.Popup/sample/sap.m.sample.p13n.Popup/code and add e.g. `<P13nFilterPanel id="filterPanel" title="Filter"/>` after the line 18 as part of the `panels` aggregation, you can see that the popup has a "Filter" panel when opened. Would it answer the question?

Comment: The problem is, that this will mix up old and new panels. Additionally we planned to use the P13nEngine (https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/#/api/sap.m.p13n.Engine) for the variant management. For the usage of the P13nEngine a controller for filtering would be needed. But thanks for the idea to add just the old FilterPanel to the dialog. This could be a possible solution.

Comment: While the current state is not a "bug", you could still [create a new issue on OpenUI5 GitHub](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/new). Even if it's not planned to provide a "newer" filter panel, I guess at least the samples and/or API reference could be improved.